# npm i Running command - failed! (exit code 254)

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, ionic3

Ionic :3.20.0

node: v8.10.0

npm: 5.6.0

> npm i
>       ✖ Running command - failed!
>       [ERROR] An error occurred while running npm i (exit code 254):

```
npm ERR! path 
/Users/lucaszimmermann/Desktop/myApp/node_modules/tsickle/src/main.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 
'/Users/lucaszimmermann/Desktop/myApp/node_modules/tsickle/src/main.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     
/Users/lucaszimmermann/.npm/_logs/2018-04-04T16_41_39_270Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Please provide the content of `/Users/lucaszimmermann/.npm/_logs/2018-04-04T16_41_39_270Z-debug.log` - This will be not listen without reason...

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar issue after doing the below actions this issue solved.

1. Delete `package-lock.json` file.
2. Open cmd/terminal in administrator mode.
3. run command: `npm install`
4. run command: `npm update`

Answer (score 0):

Node version is likely incompatible. There'd be an expected version actual version. Use `nvm` or similar to install and change node versions.

Delete `node_modules` and try install again. You probably get a message similar to:

```
error ts-jest@26.1.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">= 10.21.0". Got "10.20.1"
error Found incompatible module.
```

Answer (score -10):

You wan't try to install `npm` packages.
You have **two options** to install some packages:

**First Option:**

> npm install <package>
>
> npm i <package>

**Second Option:**

If you wan't to create an **automated installation process** without each package, you must **provide** an `packge.json` - Here are all depencies listed. You can only run `npm i` or `npm install` without an package name, if you have an `package.json`

A full documentation about that is on NPM: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

Comment: Not. Than, he had transmit more informations like Error Logs and other ;) thanks for downvote :)))

Comment: The downvote is because you haven't answered the question, you've answered "How do I install things via NPM" rather than addressing the exact issue at hand, you can't just loosely answer a question and claim the questioner didn't provide enough for you to go from.